# SQL - Show all dates in a given range and count how many posts there are on that date using a timestamp from database

Tags: mysql, sql, date, charts, timestamp

I have created a query that will count the number of posts and group them by the date, however the result doesn't show the dates when there were no posts.

QUERY:

```
SELECT DATE(Date_Uploaded) AS ForDate
     , COUNT(*) AS NumPosts 
  FROM Articles 
 WHERE 'Status'='4' 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(Date_Uploaded) 
 ORDER 
    BY ForDate
```

for info 'Status' = 4 means the post is published on the site and 'Date_Uploaded' is the timestamp of publication.

This will for example return;

- 2020-09-10: 2
- 2020-09-14: 1
- 2020-09-25: 4

However I want;

- 2020-09-10: 2
- 2020-09-11: 0
- 2020-09-12: 0
- 2020-09-13: 0
- 2020-09-14: 1

etc.

The reason I need my data like this is so I can use it with google charts to create a column chart that shows the number of posts over time. by not including the dates with no posts the chart will not format the missing dates.

If there is a way to still use the same query but have google charts space the data appropriately this would also be a great solution.

Thanks.

EDIT: The date range would be defined on the same page I intend to place the chart using the data

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You need to get your dates from somewhere. Many people find a "numbers table" helpful, and this could be a use for it - combined with a date 'seed' based on the run date. You at least need to consider specifying a date range (the last x days?).

Comment: It might be helpful to know your DBMS (and version) eg SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (such as missing data) in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data for all dates, but just not for `status = 4`, then you can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT DATE(Date_Uploaded) AS ForDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumPosts
FROM Articles 
GROUP BY DATE(Date_Uploaded)
ORDER BY ForDate;
```

Otherwise, you need to use a table that has dates (or numbers) or generate them and use `LEFT JOIN`.  However, the exact syntax depends on the database.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2020-09-10') as date
      union all
      select date + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where date < '2020-09-25'
     ) 
select d.date, count(a.date_uploaded)
from dates d left join
     articles a
     on a.date_uploaded >= d.date and
        a.date_uploaded < d.date + interval 1 day and
        a.status = 4
group by d.date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately even if I don't look at Status = 4, there still isn't data for all dates. 

Would creating a new table be the only solution I have then?

Comment: @callumcheney . . . **tag your question with the database you are using**.

Comment: @callumcheney . . . In MySQL, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates.  I modified the answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! your solution using recursive dates works and gives me exactly what I will need.